# Can't find a side number's font

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texstudio, russian

I'm actually spent like 20+hr trying to find it. I need your help.
[image: Text]

Comment: if that's a typeset book the exact font may not be available digitally or may not be free, what particular font features are you looking for and which of the fonts shown, the main upright body font on line 1, the italic on line 2 or the sans serif used in the diagonal labels?

Comment: I need side number's font. It similar to sans serif, but there is no exact style of '1', '2' and '3' in the internet, I could find. This book was written in LaTeX, so it should be available.

Comment: you should put that in the question! are you sure the graphs were made with latex not imported as image?

Comment: the numbers on the labels are _weird_ almost hand drawn, the 8 in 80 on the left has a very small top bowl and doesn't match the 8 at the top, I don't think the very stylised 2 in 120 on the left matches the  20 lower down either, the 8 at the bottom is not the same as the one at the top..... I suspect these _are_ hand drawn.

Comment: Put it. Than you! 
As I was told it was made with tikz package, but now I think you're right.

Comment: Just looking at the various zeroes, they all differ slightly … Hand-drawn it is IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this particular example does indeed seem hand-drawn, the font clearly tries to resemble some variant of [ISO 3098 / ГОСТ 2.304-81 font](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%91%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82). If I correctly remember my secondary school classes of technical drawing (черчение), this is the font that was recommended (or even required) for all technical drawings in Soviet Union and probably still is in Russia, so nothing strange that you see it on that plot. (We were even taught to properly draw these letters!)

After some googling, I found another TeX.SE question that discusses this font: [Technical drawing in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405285/technical-drawing-in-latex), which in turn refers to [osifont project](https://github.com/hikikomori82/osifont). You will probably need to set it to italic:

[image]

Comment: that's probably a more useful answer than mine:-) +1

Comment: Hand-drawn for sure.  In the U.S., a not-so-skilled draftsman would have used a Leroy set (the accepted style in the U.S.), but an experienced draftsman could get away with labeling a plot by hand.  (My summer job as an undergraduate was drafting wind tunnel plots.  B.C. -- Before Computers.)

Comment: Спасибо! Вы меня спасли.
Это именно он, чертежный шрифт. Не понимаю, как я этого не заметил.

Answer (score 2):

The figure appears to be hand drawn (or at least the labels hand written)

The 8 in 80 on the left has a very small top bowl and doesn't match the 8 at the top, I don't think the very stylised 2 in 120 on the left matches the 20 lower down either, the 8 at the bottom is not the same as the one at the top